# Google Chrome Dev Tools: Padding vs Margin

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Can someone explain why padding and margins make Google Chrome Dev Tools report a different width for content.

Here's an example:

HTML

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
// Dev Tools reports the DIV has a width of 320px
.box {
  padding: 10px;
}

// BUT here Dev Tools reports the DIV has a width of 300px
.box {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In box model, the width is calculated in two ways:

1. `border-box` (calculation includes `border` and `padding`)
2. `content-box` (calculation excludes `border` and `padding`, default)

If it's gonna be `border-box`, then the values of `padding` and `border` will be added twice with the `width` and `height`.

[image]
<sub>(source: [binvisions.com](http://www.binvisions.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/css-box-model-border-content_590x328.jpg))</sub>

The `margin` is never included in the calculation of `width`. That's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Margin is added outside the div box. That means, if you have a div box of width 300px with a margin of 10px, your div box will be of 300px in width and will be placed leaving space of 10px all around it.

Whereas, padding is added inside the div box. That means, if you have a div box of 300px with a padding of 10px, the 10px space will be added inside the div box (both horizontally and vertically). Therefore total width of div will be 300px + 10px(right) + 10px(left) = 320px.The contents inside div box can occupy only 300px of the width, leaving 10px of spacing all around them inside div.